# Integration of Ricci curvature on a compact manifold.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, curvature, connections

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Let, $(M,g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold and $X\in \chi(M).$ Show that $\int Ric_g(X,X)\mu_g=\int ((tr(\nabla_.X))^2-tr(\nabla_.X\circ \nabla_.X))\mu_g.$

$\mathbf {My \  approach}:$ There's a hint: to use $\int_M \Delta f  \mu_g=0$ where $\Delta f$ is Laplacian of $f.$

I started with $\nabla$ is torsion-free .
Define $\operatorname{T}(v)=\nabla_vX$ then $\operatorname{T}:T_pM\to T_pM$ is linear for each $p\in M.$

Let, $p\in M$ and $(U,\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n)$ be a normal neighbourhood around $p.$

Now,$\nabla_X(\nabla_{e_i}X)=\nabla_{\nabla_{e_i}X}X+[X,\nabla_{e_i}X]
\implies \nabla_{e_i}(\nabla_XX)-R(e_i,X)X-\nabla_{[e_i,X]}X=\nabla_{\nabla_{e_i}X}X+[X,\nabla_{e_i}X]
\implies R(e_i,X)X=\nabla_{e_i}(\nabla_XX)-\nabla_{[e_i,X]}X-\nabla_{\nabla_{e_i}X}X-[X,\nabla_{e_i}X]
\implies R(e_i,X)X=\nabla_{e_i}(\nabla_XX)-\nabla_X(\nabla_{e_i}X)-\operatorname{T}\circ \operatorname{T}(e_i)$ where we used $\nabla_{e_i}X=[e_i,X]$ as $\nabla$ is torsion-free and again we use torsion-freeness on two vector fields $X$ and  $[e_i,X].$ Then taking trace of the left side and of $\operatorname{T}\circ \operatorname{T},$ we obtain 2 terms in the expression but I can't proceed after this .

I don't know how to bring $(tr(\nabla_.X))^2.$

Do we need to start with $f(p)=\frac{1}{2}\langle X,X\rangle(p) ?$

Thanks in advance for any help .

Comment: It seems to me that this integral identity should be connected with Bochner's formula, see for example Corollary 1.4 in these notes: http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~wangzuoq/Courses/16S-RiemGeom/Notes/Lec27.pdf . If you substitute $X^\flat$ for the $1$-form $\omega$ and integrate you obtain something very similar to the identity you want to prove. Do you have a source for this?

Comment: It was an exercise given during our Riemannian Geometry lecture .

Comment: Very well, let me know if you find the Bochner formula helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I looked at Theorem $1.5$ of page $4.$ But there's a condition that $\mathcal{b}X$ is a closed $1-$form. And again I can't see how to bring the expression $(tr(\operatorname{T}))^2$ ?

Comment: Instead of Theorem $1.5$ you can take Corollary $1.4$ for $\omega=X^\flat$. That has no extra hypothesis. Integrating, it seems to me that one finds $\int Ric(X,X)=\int\left(\lvert d^*X^\flat\rvert^2+\lvert d X^\flat\rvert^2-\lvert\nabla X^\flat\rvert^2\right)$. the first piece is what you are looking for: $\lvert d^*X^\flat\rvert^2=Tr(\nabla X)^2$. I am at a loss for the other terms, however.

Comment: Okay, thank you !!

Answer (score 2):

Using the abstract index notation, we can rewrite the identity in question as
$$
\int_M Ric_{a b}X^a X^b \mu_g = \int_M \big( (\nabla_a X^a)^2 - (\nabla_a X^b) (\nabla_b X^a) \big) \mu_g
$$

To show that this holds on a closed (compact, without boundary) manifold $M$, equipped with a Riemannian metric $g$, and $\nabla$ being the Levi-Civita connection for $g$, we can start from the definition of the Riemann curvature operator:
$$
Riem_{a b}{}^{c}{}_{d}X^d = \nabla_a \nabla_b X^c - \nabla_b \nabla_a X^c
$$

Taking into account that $Ric_{b d} := Riem_{a b}{}^{a}{}_{d}$ by definition, we get:
$$
Ric_{b d} X^b X^d = X^b \nabla_a \nabla_b X^a - X^b \nabla_b \nabla_a X^a
$$

Renaming the dummy indices of the first term on the right-hand side, we see that
$$
Ric_{b d} X^b X^d = X^a \nabla_b \nabla_a X^b - X^b \nabla_b \nabla_a X^a \tag{1}
$$

By the Leibniz rule, we have the identities
$$
\nabla_b (X^a \nabla_a X^b) = (\nabla_b X^a)(\nabla_a X^b) + X^a \nabla_b \nabla_a X^b \tag{2}
$$
and
$$
\nabla_b (X^b \nabla_a X^a) = (\nabla_b X^b) (\nabla_a X^a) + X^b \nabla_b \nabla_a X^a \tag{3}
$$
which we can use to express the terms on the right-hand side of $(1)$ as follows:
$$
Ric_{b d} X^b X^d = \nabla_b(X^a \nabla_a X^b) - (\nabla_b X^a)(\nabla_a X^b) - \nabla_b(X^b \nabla_a X^a) + (\nabla_b X^b) (\nabla_a X^a)
$$

The left-hand sides of both $(2)$ and $(3)$ are in the [divergence form](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4483299/2002), so the corresponding terms (1-st and 3-rd) integrate to zero over a closed manifold.